# "No Windows Console found. Are you running cmd.exe?"

Tags: python, windows, prompt-toolkit

All I did was copy and pasted some example code from PyInquirer into my IDE and it doesn't work and I am confused as to why.

THE CODE:

```
   from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
from PyInquirer import prompt
from pprint import pprint
questions = [
    {
        'type': 'input',
        'name': 'first_name',
        'message': 'What\'s your first name',
     }
]
answers = prompt(questions)
pprint(answers)
```

THE ERROR:

```
C:\Users\minch\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe C:\Users\minch\PycharmProjects\Unicorn\Transformations.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\minch\PycharmProjects\Unicorn\Transformations.py", line 11, in <module>
    answers = prompt(questions)
  File "C:\Users\minch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\PyInquirer\prompt.py", line 69, in prompt
    answer = run_application(
  File "C:\Users\minch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 576, in run_application
    output=create_output(true_color=true_color))
  File "C:\Users\minch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\shortcuts.py", line 118, in create_output
    return Win32Output(stdout)
  File "C:\Users\minch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 80, in __init__
    info = self.get_win32_screen_buffer_info()
  File "C:\Users\minch\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\prompt_toolkit\terminal\win32_output.py", line 172, in get_win32_screen_buffer_info
    raise NoConsoleScreenBufferError
prompt_toolkit.terminal.win32_output.NoConsoleScreenBufferError: No Windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Why is this happening?

Comment: The "prompt" function expects a real console window but the IDE probably tries to run the code in some simple input/output window. Run the code from command line outside of IDE or maybe the IDE provides an option to do that automatically.

Comment: Can you please add the name of your IDE? Maybe some one can help you with some setting that you have to enable to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

That error comes when you use a very simple IDE input output as @micheal butscher has said.

Use the cmd.exe or terminal emulator (wt.exe, etc)
This happens on thonny for me also. While using prompt_toolkit

Answer (score 1):

This error came to me when using Windows PowerShell ISE. I resolved it by switching to the cmd prompt.